# Pandas groupby + mean + values giving array need dtype as float

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'region': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690],
   'time':[71,21,8,63,41,12,56,88,94,21,42,90],
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)

df[df.region==2].groupby('time').mean().values[0]

array([Value])
```

if I do pandas groupby agg as above. I get array as output. What I need is Val as output instead of array([Val]). how to do?

Comment: it would be much easier to answer if you provided a reproducible example

Comment: @mozway: added reproducible example.

Comment: Your groupby command returns a list of lists. You need to do something like: `df[df.region==2].groupby('time').mean().values[0][0]`.

Comment: why do you get the mean of **all** columns if you then plan to subset? what exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: please add the expected result

Comment: Using groupby is to group the particular column with the same value, however, in your sample, the values for `time` are all different.. If you just want to sort the dataframe based on the time, use this: `df[df.region==2].sort_values(by='time')`